# Is there any simplest way to upgrade old projects without editing the gradle file manually?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some old Android Studio projects. If I open them with the newest Android Studio installed, I want the following settings (except for `minSdkVersion`)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allyourcode.a02_01"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    }
}
```

are upgraded to the latest version available on the web. Editing manually seems to be tedious for me.

## Question

Is there any  simplest way to upgrade old Android Studio projects without editing the gradle file manually?

Comment: One workaround is to use the dangerous plus sign (+) in your project version. IMHO editing your `Gradle` takes only small effort or did I miss something?

Comment: Only few places need modify, so why tedious :) , and you could find and replace same literal string.